# Xcode compile time too long

Tags: xcode

I don't know if this question belongs here but I need help to figure out a solution to this problem because Apple developer support hasn’t responded since almost 3 months.

Version 9.0 beta 5 (9M202q)
MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011)
macOS HighSierra version 10.13.1 (17B48)

Every time I compile a program in Xcode it takes atleast 7 minutes to simulate the application. Around 90% of attempts, the program doesn’t even compile inspite of generating a successful build. Common error messages that show up are the following :
Could not attach to pid : "1050"
Failed to initiate service connection to simulator

Can anyone please help me ?

Warm regards.

Comment: 1) Xcode 9.1 has already been released. Update to latest version
2) Profile the code that you compile. You can use Swift Build Time Analyzer (google that) which will show you which function takes the longest to compile.
3) Once you found which code takes longest to compile - post a question with that code so that people can help you optimize compile time for it.

Comment: @ Eimantas : Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I downloaded Xcode version 9.2 beta (9C34b) last night with no improvement. In fact it is taking even longer. There are no functions other than the default ones that are created when you create a Single View Application. I have only added 1 label and 4 buttons on the storyboard to start with. Nevertheless I will downloard Swift Build Time Analyzer to check if that helps.

Comment: @ Eimantas : It really isn't a question of which function is taking too long to compile. I have not written any functions in the program and it's still showing error messages cited in my question. Thanks for your advice anyways.

Comment: If you want to be sure everything is stable - update to production release versions (in this case - Xcode 9.1). It could also help removing old/outdated simulators if you have them installed (i.e. iOS 9 and below).

Comment: I have removed Xcode version 9.2 beta and installed version 9.1 (9B55). Unfortunately I haven't experienced any improvement in the compile time. I am completely perplexed by this problem and don't know how to solve it :( It's frustratingly  difficult to learn how to program on your own in these conditions. The absence of Apple developer support isn't helping at all. Thanks again for your suggestions. Wish you all the best.